# What does the Number Parrot do?

Tags: mathematics

The Number Parrot lives in a zoo close to one small college in England. Parrots love to repeat what people say. But the Number Parrot is slightly different. When you say an integer, it replies with another integer.

Examples of what the Number Parrot replies:

```
 question   answer
 0          0
 1          1
 5          3
 9          4
 24         2
 441        100 
 -45        -12 
 -1000      -27
```

What does the Number Parrot actually do?

Comment: Natural numbers are positive. Did you mean integers?

Comment: I hope the answer is not a some kind of polinomial function...

Comment: It would be nice to know what the parrot does on an *infinite* sequence of numbers, say over the two powers, or primes. Or, a way to measure in an *objective* way how good a potential answer is. Otherwise, you might have a crazy parrot which answers 0 as a response to *all other* questions...

Comment: @Matsmath Thanks for explaining what you don't like about the puzzle. But sorry, I don't really get your point. I know that you can think out infinitely many "correct" answers to the question as there is infinitely many functions $f\colon\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f$ is valued as above. However, (1) this is still true even if I give out a whole series of numbers as long as I don't give out all of them (but how would it be a puzzle after this anymore?) and (2) I made pretty sure that there is only one really good answer.

Comment: I'm still happy for the 4 users here who find the Number Parrot interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let the parrot get a number:

> $x=\alpha p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2}p_3^{n_3}...$ with $\alpha\in\{-1,0,1\}$, $p_x$ is the $x^{th}$ prime and $n_x$ are all non-negative integers.

Then the parrot says:

> $\alpha p_1^{n_2}p_2^{n_3}p_3^{n_4}...$, i.e. each prime in the prime representation of $x$ is changed to the prime before it, except any power of $2$ is dropped, but positivity/negativity ($\alpha$) is retained.

The examples:

> First we note that $p_1=2$, $p_2=3$, $p_3=5$ and $p_4=7$. These are the only primes we need to explain the examples.
>  For $0$, $\alpha=0$, so the parrot says $0$.
>  For $1$, $\alpha=1$ and for all $x$, $n_x=0$, so the parrot says $1$.
>  For $5$, $\alpha=1$ and for all $x\neq 3$, $n_x=0$, with $n_3=1$, so the parrot says $1\cdot p_2^1=3$.
>  For $9$, $\alpha=1$ and for all $x\neq 2$, $n_x=0$, with $n_2=2$, so the parot says $1\cdot p_1^2=4$.
>  For $24$, $\alpha=1$ and for all $x\neq 1,2$, $n_x=0$ with $n_1=3$ and $n_2=1$, but $n_1$ is not used in the output, so the parrot says $1\cdot p_1^1=2$.
>  For $441$, $\alpha=1$ and for all $x\neq 2,4$, $n_x=0$ with $n_2=2$ and $n_4=2$, so the parrot says $1\cdot p_1^2p_3^2=100$.
>  For $-45$, $\alpha=-1$ and for all $x\neq 2,3$, $n_x=0$ with $n_2=2$ and $n_3=1$, so the parrot says $-1\cdot p_1^2p_2^1=-12$.
>  For $-1000$, $\alpha=-1$ and for all $x\neq 1,3$, $n_x=0$ with $n_1=3$ and $n_3=3$, but $n_1$ is not used in the output, so the parrot says $-1\cdot p_2^3=-27$.